# How to determine the effect of a singularity of a function entering the ODE on the solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singularity

Let $R:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a given function and let us consider the following Riccati differential equation:
$$
f''(t)+f'(t)^2-R(t)=0.
$$
My question is: Is there any theory (please, provide a book, paper whatever) which allows to determine what is the effect of a discontinuity of the function $R(t)$ on the solution of the ODE?
I am also interested in understanding whether a change of concavity of the function produces a well-determined effect on the solution of the ODE.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further properties on that $R(t)$ I think that there's not too much to say. I would say that, in general, questions specifics like this are solved with a combination of well know inequalities, bounds, etc and some "exploration" over the, a priori selected, particular properties of the coefficients. Take a look on [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2099540) for example of what I'm saying.

Suppose that the kind of function $R(t)$ has a finite discontinuity like [the sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). So your equation becomes:
$$y'=-y^2+sgn(x)$$
So what you really have is a vector field in $R^2$ that is obtained by gluing together two smooth vector fields:
$$x'=1$$
$$y'=-y^2-1$$
for $(x,y)$ with $x\le0$, and
$$x'=1$$
$$y'=-y^2+1$$
for $(x,y)$ with $x>0$. And, in this case, the effect of the discontinuity will be the appearance of a sharp corner in the solutions.

[image]

Comment: Dear @Diego, Thanks a lot for your interesting answer.
In effect, my question is general since the function, $R(t)$, could take any shape.
Nevertheless, in order to be preciser, I wish to know how any variation in $R(t)$ is reflected in $f(t)$. For example, if $R(t)$ presents an inflection point, what is the effect on $f(t)$ or on its derivatives? Conversely, if $R(t)$ is always convex or concave, do the function $f(t)$ or its derivatives maintain the same convexity or concavity? More generically, Is not there any classification of this kind for a certain class of differential equation?

Comment: This kind of question can be analysed with phase space methods.